# Como usar Navigator.push dentro de um widget

Tags: flutter, route, widget

Sou novo em Flutter e estou tentando criar uma nova tela/rota a partir de uma condição if-else. Se a condição for satisfeita/true, quero mostrar uma imagem em "tela cheia" sendo uma nova tela.

O objetivo é mostrar uma imagem em tela cheia toda vez que a variável bpm_display for maior do que um valor pré-estabelecido bpm_limit_display. O objetivo final do app é monitorar o batimento cardíaco e mostrar uma imagem sempre que o batimento ultrapassar um limite.
Neste app, estou simulando o valor do batimento com um botão que aumenta o valor de uma variável bom. Quando batimento reduzir, quero retornar para a tela inicial e recomeçar o ciclo de verificação.

Tenho a classe ImagesPage1 para mostrar a imagem, porém na condição if-else a imagem fica dentro do widget da rota atual e não cria uma nova rota. O Navigator.push retorna um erro (The element type 'Future' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.) e não consegui corrigir. Se usar um botão, o app abre uma nova tela com a imagem cheia, exatamente como eu preciso. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called.
    //
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var bpm_display = appState.bpm;
    var bpm_limit_display = appState.bpm_limit;

        
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('BPM:'),
            Text(
              bpm_display.toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            // este bloco if-else está dentro do widget e não aceita navigator
            if (bpm_display > bpm_limit_display)
              //ImagesPage1() // esta linha funciona, porém a imagem fica dentro do widget atual e não cria uma nova rota
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImagesPage1()),
                ); //essa linha não funciona
            else Text('BPM ok'),

            SizedBox(width: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                appState.update_bpm();
              },
              child: Text('Aumentar BPM'),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                appState.downgrade_bpm();
              },
              child: Text('Diminuir BPM'),
            ),

            //este bloco cria outra tela com a imagem após clicar no botão exatamente como preciso, não funciona no bloco de IF
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Open route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImagesPage1()),
                );
              },
            ),
         ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Fala @lpgomes, bem vindo ao site. Não sei se entendi muito bem o comportamento que você deseja. Entendi que você quer mostrar um Widget como uma nova tela, baseado em uma condição (if). Porém, minha dúvida é em *qual* momento você deseja que essa condição seja verificada? O método build é um método que deve retornar como o Widget em questão deve se desenhar. Ele vai ser chamado sempre que houver alguma alteração de layout. Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar esses pontos que mencionei? Um abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Porque você quer que seja em outra rota? A tela anterior precisaria ser essa?

Comment: Oi @Naslausky, muito obrigado pelos seus comentários. Editei minha pergunta e espero ter conseguido explicar melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `build` tem um retorno e este retorno pode ser dependente da sua variável.

Ao invés de usar o `push` para uma nova tela, experimente retornar a tela correta baseado na variável:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var bpm_display = appState.bpm;
    var bpm_limit_display = appState.bpm_limit;

    if (bpm_display > bpm_limit_display){
        return ImagesPage1();
    }    

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
// [...] // Resto de seu código
```

Isto deve trazer o comportamento esperado: Quando a variável passar do limite, a imagem aparecerá, e caso volte a estar dentro do limite irá mostrar a primeira tela novamente.